# How to enable the frame pointer?

Tags: c++, g++, cmake

I've been looking around and I can only seem to find the option to omit the frame pointer.

Here are the compile flags that I'm using right now.

```
-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wold-style-cast -g
```

Can someone tell me how to *enable* the frame pointer?

**Note** I'm using g++ version 4.6.6 on RHEL 6.2

Comment: Perhaps don't include the option for omitting it? (Boolean logic...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any optimization level (`-O`, `-O2`, `-O3`), enable `-fomit-frame-pointer`, but you can revert it with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`. You can find more details here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html